# Press and hold settings sense?

Tags: windows, pen

What is the sense of two different settings in `Press and Hold Setting` dialog?

[image]

First called "speed", but also can be "short" and "long". Can something have "short" or "long" speed? If "long" speed stays for "big" speed then the amount of time should be small, because time is in denominator in speed!

What about wet weight or sweet topology of cosmology? :)